# HttpServlet is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, noclassdeffounderror, kepler

I am getting the following error when running a basic servlet on Eclipse Kepler (Windows 7) with GAE SDK 1.9.3 and Java 7:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet is a restricted class.
Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

To reproduce:

1. install Java 7 SDK
2. install Kepler
3. install the GAE Eclipse plugin
4. create a GAE web project
5. implement the init method of a basic servlet and set `load-on-startup` to `1` in `web.xml`
6. then run the web application

I tried on 2 machines and I got the same error.

Comment: Could you provide the code for step 5?

Comment: Just override the init(ServletConfig config) in the servlet and System out something.  The method will be called at startup if load-on-startup is set to 1.

Comment: Update: I am getting the same kind of error if I use an incorrect url.  For example: http://localhost:8888/abc:

Problem accessing /abc. Reason:
    javax.servlet.FilterChain is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
Caused by:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.FilterChain is a restricted class.

I don't understand why this restricted class error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a servlet by extending HttpServlet, then Override `doPost()` and `doGet()` methods in your servlets. For example:

```
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found what was wrong and it was my mistake.  Sorry.  When I installed Java 7, I specified a different directory for the JDK and the JRE, which is fine, except that I gave the same location twice and the files got mixed up.  My GAE issue was a side effect.